# How to create a div where it show a picture by default but transitions to some text details when you hover over it?

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions

I want to create a div.
It is 300 x 300 px.
By default it has a picture in it.
But when you hover over it, you it transitions to a text description.
There should also be a transition period of 0.2 sec.

I could not figure our how to do that. Please help.

```css
main, .front, .back {
height:300px;
width:300px;
}

.back{
display:none;
}

.front:hover .back {
display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main"> 
  
  <div class="front">
  <img src="https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/lawn-pH.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
  </div>
  
  <div class="back">
    <h1>Image Name</h1>
    <p>Image description blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.front,
.back {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.back {
  transform: translateY(-80%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.front:hover .back {
  opacity: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="front">
  <img src="https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/lawn-pH.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
  <div class="back">
    <h1>Image Name</h1>
    <p>Image description </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will work!

If You want to hide image then:

```css
.front,
.back {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

#image {
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.back {
  transform: translateY(-80%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.front:hover .back {
  opacity: 100;
}

.front:hover #image {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="front">
  <img id="image" src="https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/lawn-pH.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
  <div class="back">
    <h1>Image Name</h1>
    <p>Image description </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.main, .front, .back {
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  position: relative;
}

.back{    
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 6em 1em;
  text-align: center;
  top: -100%;
  right: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #333333;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
} 

.main:hover .back {
    display: block;
    top: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main"> 
  
  <div class="front">
  <img src="https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/lawn-pH.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
  </div>
  <div class="back">
    <h1>Image Name</h1>
    <p>Image description blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah  </p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: the problem i got from this is that the contents in the "back" class is not invisible when the area is not hovered on. it is above it.